# Losing Access Tokens on refreshing redirected page

Tags: reactjs, spotify, spotify-app

So the access token authentication with Spotify works fine if I log in via the authentication flow. But if I press refresh on my 'Home' page (the page that the authentication redirects to), without logging out and logging back in. My token variable that's suppose to store the access token becomes a null value in the console. I notice other Spotify API built web-apps allow users to be automatically logged in when you enter their url without having to redirect the user to the Spotify login authentication. I'm not sure how to get to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable that you have in memory will be lost on refresh. One solution could be to save the token in local storage right when you get it, and check if it exists when you load the application. Local storage persists refreshes and revisits so it would be the quickest solution. After that you could check more secure routes.